# How to parse the geolocation json from google for lng and lat in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json, geolocation

I'm creating a web request to pull lng and lat data based on zip (using the following url)

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=50266

Doing so I get back the following json

```
{
  "name": "50266",
  "Status": {
    "code": 200,
    "request": "geocode"
  },
  "Placemark": [ {
    "id": "p1",
    "address": "West Des Moines, IA 50266, USA",
    "AddressDetails": {
   "Accuracy" : 5,
   "Country" : {
      "AdministrativeArea" : {
         "AdministrativeAreaName" : "IA",
         "Locality" : {
            "LocalityName" : "West Des Moines",
            "PostalCode" : {
               "PostalCodeNumber" : "50266"
            }
         }
      },
      "CountryName" : "USA",
      "CountryNameCode" : "US"
   }
},
    "ExtendedData": {
      "LatLonBox": {
        "north": 41.6005010,
        "south": 41.5254700,
        "east": -93.7347000,
        "west": -93.8435030
      }
    },
    "Point": {
      "coordinates": [ -93.7353858, 41.5998115, 0 ]
    }
  } ]
}
```

What I'm trying to pull from this is simply the coordinates section. Here is my current attempt that throws and exception when I hit the last line shown below

```
  //after I get the response I turn it into json and this is working
  NSArray* json = [items JSONValue];

  NSString* coords = [json objectForKey:@"Placemark.Point.coordinates"];
```

What I'm I missing here for a quick pull of the coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall value return is not an array, it's a dictionary.  Note that the first character is `{`.  If it were an array, it would be `[`.

```
NSDictionary * json = [string JSONValue];
```

Now, you want the stuff under the "Placemarks" key.  Note that this returns an array, since the character after the "Placemarks" key (and colon) is a `[`.

```
NSArray * placemarks = [json objectForKey:@"Placemark"];
```

From this array, you want the first element, which is another `NSDictionary`:

```
NSDictionary *firstPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
```

From this dictionary, you want the dictionary under the key "Point":

```
NSDictionary *point = [firstPlacemark objectForKey:@"Point"];
```

From this dictionary, you want the array under the key "coordinates":

```
NSArray * coordinates = [point objectForKey:@"coordinates"];
```

At this point, you have the array that contains 3 `NSNumber` objects.  Voilá!

---

<strike>For the advanced user, you can probably use key-value coding to get at it:</strike>

```
NSArray * coordinates = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Placemark[0].Point.coordinates"];
```

Though I wouldn't recommend that unless you clearly understand what's going on there.

That does not work.  Never mind! :)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you much! Just one comment - the final "advanced section" didn't work (not sure why) also I updated the first NSArray to be "Placemark" instead of the plural.

Comment: @Toran yeah, i'd have to play with it some more.  i just typed all that in the browser and didn't actually *try* it.... ;)

Comment: @Toran maybe because i typod and put "Placemarks" instead of "Placemark"?  That's the main problem with Key-Value coding: there's no type checking involved, since it's just strings...

Comment: Right - I appreciate the help regardless!  I did try the single "Placemark" version (advanced) with no luck but I'm fine w/ the long version (as you mentioned ... new devs might benefit from the verbose approach)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that "[ -93.7353858, 41.5998115, 0 ]" is not a string